# What would the internet/web look like if the Soviet Union had won the Cold War?

Tags: alternate-history, technological-development, internet, communism

Supposing the capitalist bloc collapsed in 1990 instead.

The end of the cold War (actually) coincided with the beginning of the internet, with the Soviet Union being assigned a TLD (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.su) just before its collapse, and some personal computers ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agat_(computer) ) being created by the communist bloc, with a very Soviet æsthetic.

Capitalist imperatives have obviously shaped the way our web works today: advertising, quick delivery of consumer products, etc. But what if the past 30 years had played out under a different economic and political system? How would our ICT infrastructure have developed, æsthetically, economically, technically, in that scenario?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding, please take a good read at our [help] to make yourself familiar with this community and its standards. At the moment you are asking 4 different questions, while we prefer one question per post. Can you edit your post accordingly?

Comment: This question is asking for opinion. There are political questions that would need to be answered first. For example, would the "Cold War" have continued during that time? How would the Soviet politicians view the fledgling internet? How much would they have participated in places like CERN (where the WWW was developed)?

Comment: Can you detail how the Soviet Union won the war in your scenario? It's hardly possible to make a guess if we don't know how they or the opponent are doing after it : Are the USA totally out of the political and cultural game, for instance? How do the other countries like, I don't know UK or France, stand, at least in general : Did they flip to communism? Did they break the OTAN treaty or other treaties? In your world, are the people who made internet the same or are they from Eastern Europe? Not all of the above need/should be answered, but you see a possible approach to detail your question.

Comment: What are the words "the capitalist bloc collapsed" supposed to mean? And are India and China included in that "capitalist bloc"? (BTW, the SU had no intention of winning the cold war. In fact, ever since the early 1970s they were in a defensive mood.) (The Soviet Union was nowhere near the top of the IT industry in the Eastern Block. They were rather backward, in fact. For example, Robotron in the DDR made very decent PCs and printers, with a decidedly not Soviet aesthetic. Several countries also made more-or-less compatible clones of the Digital Equipment Corporation PDP-11 and VAX-11.)

Comment: Could you provide more details about the economic and political systems in your world? I am afraid that without this information most answers will be based on propagandist descriptions of the Soviet culture and economy rather than actual reality.

Comment: @philipp if you were to roll your own answer into the question, this could probably be reopened for people to expound on further, as I think you provide the missing added clarity in your answer. If you don’t mind, I can do this for you?

Comment: What internet? There wouldn't be one. As with all communist societies, it wasn't in the interests of the authorities for the masses to have easy access to information & knowledge. It's easier to control people that way & the authorities can remain in power unimpeded.

Answer (score 3):

An internet developed by an authoritarian socialist state like the Soviet Union would mimic its ideology:

- Centralization instead of decentralization
- Censorship instead of freedom of information
- Accountability instead of anonymity
- Surveillance instead of privacy

The Soviet Union believed in a centralized, planned economy. So it is unlikely that anyone could just put a server on the Internet and offer any information they want. The Soviet leadership would only allow services they authorized and which they can control. So if you want to offer an online service, you would have to write a request to your local party official where you explain how your service will work and how it will further the Soviet cause. When your request gets rejected, then do not expect an explanation or yet alone an appeal process.

When your service offers information, then the party will want to control and censor that information. A web 2.0 service where user-generated content can be published without prior moderation would be unthinkable.

If the service allows user-generated content to be posted (after review, of course), then there likely won't be anonymous postings. Any active participation would be clearly linked to the person responsible. Not necessarily for everyone to see, but certainly visible to the KGB.

User access would also be tracked and stored. Even though there is not much to see: Suspicious access patterns can still be a way to spot dissent.

Needless to say that an online environment like this would not give nearly as much room for experimentation and expressions as the Internet. Which means that the web would develop a lot slower than in our timeline. The aesthetics and technical capabilities of websites would likely still be stuck on the level of the early 90s.

Answer (score 0):

#### It probably looks like Project Cybersyn.

[Project Cybersyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Cybersyn) was an attempt by the communist government of Chile in the early 1970s at creating a computerized method of controlling a planned economy, with a less top-down approach than that used by the USSR, and allowing for near-real-time monitoring of performance indicators.

In real life, it ultimately wasn't ever fully implemented because the communist government was overthrown, and a capitalist system of government was instated in its place.

However, in a reality where communism won (somehow), it's possible that Project Cybersyn was a success, and it was implemented more broadly across the world, allowing for much more efficient management of the planned economy.